# CSS only comes to effect after a short, but noticable delay

Tags: php, html, css

So as you can see, the placeholder image at the top takes like a tenth of a second to get into the size and position it is supposed to be in (the original position and size is adjusted with some CSS).

Why is there this short delay and how do I fix it?

This is the PHP I used (image source is changed, of course):

```
<img  class="headerbild" src="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png" />
```

```
<?php
    x_get_view( x_get_stack(), 'wp', 'single' );
?>
```

```
<?php
    $nonce = wp_create_nonce('wpp-token');
    $id = 'YOUR-POST-ID-HERE';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use any HTML code before `<!DOCTYPE html>`
2. Use `img` code between `<body>` and `</body>`

Your style file loading after your image file. So, the delay is happening. And i think you are adding code to the wrong PHP file. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles are added after the image. try moving your image into the `<body></body>` section of the page.

The way a browser reads the page data is line by line, starting at the top working down the page. It can't do an action (like style an image) until it gets to that line of code. So if the image comes first, then the style, then you can see changes happen right before your eyes...